# What is the index access method called?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python, what is the `[1:3]` syntax on the second line called?

```
test = (1,2,3,4,5)
print(test[1:3])
```

The second parameter ("3") seems to be the index - 1 
(3 - 1 = 2)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called [slicing](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#slicings).

The first (lower bound) and the second parameter (upper bound) are indexes. The lower bound is included, but the upper bound is excluded in the result.

Comment: For a beginner it is a good trick to count the commas: `[1:3]` -> everything between the 1st and 3rd comma.